# Symfony host restriction

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing, virtualhost

I have trouble to solve a problem with my symfony app.

Say my symfony3 app is accessible by `appsymfony.com`, I would like to restrict access to user coming from `otherappsymfony.com`, which is pointing to the same nginx virtual host, only to some route I defined.

I tried to use [host routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html) but with this configuration in my routing.yml :

```
domain:
  prefix:   /
  host: {domain}
  defaults:
     _controller: AppBundle:Default:index
     domain: otherappsymfony.com

subdomain:
  prefix:   /
  host: sub.{domain}
  defaults:
     _controller: AppBundle:Default:sub
     domain: otherappsymfony.com
```

I'm still redirected to `appsymfony.com/en/` when accessing `otherappsymfony.com`

My `debug:router`:

```
 app     ANY      ANY      otherappsymfony.com       /                                                                        
 sub     ANY      ANY      sub.otherappsymfony.com   /
```

Its always override by :

```
root         ANY      ANY      ANY          /
```

Is there a better way to implement that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following approach:

```
domain:
   prefix:   /
   host: {domain}
   defaults:
       _controller: AppBundle:Default:index
       domain: otherappsymfony.com
   requirements:
       domain: "%domain%"
```

where `%domain%` is a regexp that matches the desired domain. if any of the requirements is 'false' the route is not matched.

Source for the approach was symfony docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#advanced-routing-example